# Mock two dependencies with NestJs and Jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, nestjs, ts-jest

I'm struggling to mock two dependencies from my userService.
Here I have two dependencies: UserRepository and ProfileService

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserRepository } from '../repository/user.repository';
import { userDTO } from '../typings/user.typings';
import { ProfileService } from './profile.service';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm'


@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserRepository)
    private readonly repository: UserRepository, 
    private readonly profileService: ProfileService
    ) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }
  async addUser(user: userDTO): Promise<userDTO> {
    try {
      const userCreated = await this.repository.addUser(user);
      await this.profileService.createProfile(userCreated)
      return userCreated
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  async getUser(field: string, value: string) {
const user = await this.repository.getUser(field, value);
      return user
  }

async deleteUser(field: string, value: string) {
await this.profileService.deleteProfile(userId)
    return await this.repository.deleteUser(userId);
      }

  async getUserById(userId: string) {
    return await this.repository.getUserById(userId);
  }
  async updateUser(user: userDTO, userId: string) {
    return await this.repository.updateUser(user, userId);
  }
}
```

user.service.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from "@nestjs/testing";
import { UserService } from "../../src/services/user.services";
import { ProfileService } from "../../src/services/profile.service";
import { UserRepository } from "../../src/repository/user.repository";
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

describe('userService', () => {
    let userService: UserService;
    let mockRepository = {};
    let mockProfileService = {};

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                UserService,
                {
                    provide: getRepositoryToken(UserRepository),
                    useValue: mockRepository
                },
                {
                    provide: ProfileService,
                    useValue: mockProfileService
                },
            ],
        })
            .compile();

        userService = module.get<UserService>(UserService);
    });

    it('Should be defined', () => {
        expect(userService).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

The test works fine when I only use UserRepository, but when I tried to mock the second repository it fails with this message

```
FAIL  tests/services/user.service.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'src/models/profile.models' from '../src/repository/profile.repository.ts'
```

Can someone explain me how to mock 2 dependencies(a repository and a service).

Comment: don't use absolute paths (`src/models` etc), otherwise you'll need to adjust your jest config.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: the issue here is that **jest** (not Nest) couldn't manage to resolve the path `src/models/`, then just don't use `src/`, use relative paths.

Comment: Ineed, that was the problem. Can you explain why we have to use relative paths instead of absolute path.

Comment: I'm unsure why tbh. But you can configure that to make it work. Take a look at jest config in their docs